# Why std::locale doesn't work with std::u32string?

Tags: c++, locale, stdstring

So I am trying to use `std::tolower` with custom locale.
It works with `wstring`, but with `u32string` I receive:

> what():  std::bad_cast

This is what I do

```
auto loc = std::locale("el_GR.UTF-8");
wstring wtest{L"πρόβλημα"};
u32string utest{U"πρόβλημα"};
auto toLower = [&](auto c) { return std::toupper(c, loc); };
std::transform(wtest.begin(), wtest.end(), wtest.begin(), toLower); //ok
std::transform(utest.begin(), utest.end(), utest.begin(), toLower); //bad_cast
```

Comment: From [`std::tolower`'s possible implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower), it may use [`std::ctype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype) for which,  the only specialization guarantee is for `char`/`wchar_t`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locales are required to support `std::ctype` facets only for `char` and `wchar_t`, i.e. `std::string` and `std::wstring`. Any further specializations are optional.

It seems that the implementation you are using does not provide such a specialization for `char32_t`, i.e. `std::u32string`.

Comment: And as for today there is no alternative right?